# text not fitting to column width

Tags: two-column, text, text-manipulation, column-width

I have used a template for a 4 page double column format. It works for all the other pages up to the point shown on the screenshot (end of page 3 to page 4) , and I have no idea what has triggered this difference. (I have also tried flush left and raggedleft, and included paragraph indents to try and fix it, but the text is still not filling the full width of a column as in the previous pages. I can't see any environment change that would have triggered this change.

Many thanks for your help !

(template code below- figure 1 and 2 were part of it)

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% Comment the following line to NOT allow the usage of umlauts
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

% Start the docu

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

%\pagestyle{fancyplain}


% Title page
\title{{\bf {\}}}
\author{{\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxn}}
% supervised by {xxxxxxxxxxx}}
\date{}

% when using the pgf package the image files need to be declared; if
% the jpg or pdf there is not need for specifying their extension
\pgfdeclareimage[width=9cm]{fig_1}{fig_1} % the figure's width should not exceed the column's
\pgfdeclareimage[width=18cm]{fig_2}{fig_2}
```

Comment: The problem is probably not in the code of the preamble that you included with your post but rather in the document itself, near the place where the page format changes. Could it be that you placed the command `\centering` outside of the `figure` environment instead of inside it? Search for any centering commands near this place and check whether you have placed it correctly. If you can't find the error, please compose a *complete* minimal document that shows the error and post it here.

Comment: ah indeed, many thanks :)